# Load balanced proxy server that change the request path for an ASP.NET Core 3.0 wep app

Tags: c#, docker, authentication, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I have an asp.net core 3.0 application hosted behind a proxy server.  The URL is rewritten when forwarded to the docker image that is running the application.  I can't seem to get authentication to work as the redirect is computed to the wrong url.  When i manually fix the redirect url, the authorization end point doesn't catch the call back.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.0#scenarios-and-use-cases) seems to indicate some combination of using `UsePathBase` and/or setting the `Request.PathBase`.  I've tried this and still can't seem to get it correct.  Here is my setup.

public url: http://app.com/foo/api/1
docker url: http://docker/

When the OAuth Authentication (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth) computes the redirect, it computes `http://app.com/authorization-code/callback` which is incorrect.  I've tried manually setting the callback path to get around that issue.  However, now the `/authorization-code/callback` endpoint is not hit when the authentication server redirects back to `http://app.com/foo/api/1/authorization-code/callback`

What are the correct settings in this situation?

thanks for the help

~ Paul

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue. Thanks